# Image uploader/ordering client

Tags: web-apps, file-management, ecommerce

I'm looking for a storage, whether it can be installed on our own server/website, or an external solution, that can accomplish the following:

1. Allows customers to upload images and allows us to retrieve them
2. Provides separate storage space for each session, and disallows customers from seeing any other session space
3. Allows the storage of uncompressed images
4. Allows the customer to input order information and us to receive it, preferably with a notification that a new order has been made

All of this together seems like it might be a pretty tall order, but I figured I'd check before I started even thinking about building it myself.

Comment: Your needs are very close to a ftp server.

Comment: Very close, but do you know of any FTP solutions that either provide session metadata and separation (like, this upload is order #111023, the next is #111024, etc., and both automatically show up in separate folders), or best-case that allow customers to input some form of metadata themselves?

Comment: Do customers always create an order by uploading an image?